# How to implement google route API in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I followed [this](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#installation) tutorial and implemented a google map. I tried to use [Google Route API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions) to get direction between two locations on the map. But I'm not sure what i did wrong that I'm getting this error

> > > 1 | import Component from "./Component";  error
>
> 2 | import React from "react";
>
> 3 | import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
>
> 4 | import { compose, withProps, lifecycle } from "recompose";

Here my code

```
import Component from "./Component";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { compose, withProps, lifecycle } from "recompose";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,

} from "react-google-maps";
import { DirectionsRenderer } from "react-google-maps";

const MapWithADirectionsRenderer = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAcQjrfAudzl6Ton7GA7D-gVqOINMFE7ns =3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,

  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

      DirectionsService.route(
        {
          origin: new google.maps.LatLng(41.85073, -87.65126),
          destination: new google.maps.LatLng(41.85258, -87.65141),
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        },
        (result, status) => {
          if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            this.setState({
              directions: result
            });
          } else {
            console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  })
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
    {props.directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={props.directions} />}
  </GoogleMap>
));

ReactDOM.render(
  < DirectionsRenderer directions />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours found out what was wrong ! 
I was missing  **`&v`** after the Google API keys
originally had `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAcQjrfAudzl6Ton7GA7D-gVqOINMFE7ns =3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"`

but it should be like this :

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAcQjrfAudzl6Ton7GA7D-gVqOINMFE7ns&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
```

Also i add to add this line to top of my file: /*global google*/ -> for disable ESLint

The final code will be as following :

```
/*global google*/
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
//import { DirectionsRenderer } from "react-google-maps";
import { compose, withProps, lifecycle } from "recompose";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  DirectionsRenderer,

} from "react-google-maps";

//const google=window.google
//import { DirectionsRenderer } from "react-google-maps";

const MapWithADirectionsRenderer = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAcQjrfAudzl6Ton7GA7D-gVqOINMFE7ns&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,

  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

      DirectionsService.route(
        {
          origin: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712776, -74.005974),
          destination: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052235, -118.243683),
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        },
        (result, status) => {
          if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            this.setState({
              directions: result
            });
          } else {
            console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  })
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
    {props.directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={props.directions} />}
  </GoogleMap>
));

ReactDOM.render(
  < MapWithADirectionsRenderer directions />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```